# Failed to resolve: com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.1.4

Tags: android, gradle, mpandroidchart, jitpack

I'm using `MPAndroidChart` library in android studio. But when I'm trying to sync gradle I get an error as shown in below image.

Gradle text is here to compile `MPAndroidChart` library.

```
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.1.4'
```

[image: Error screenshot]

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Have you added `maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }` to your repositories?

Comment: Just adding to @AndrewBrooke comment, you should go to your project gradle.build and add this line on repository: maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }. My project is like this: allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

Comment: Yes there is. and i also can't find search result for _com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart_ in Choose library dependancy in Project sturucture --> app --> Dependancy --> +(add) --> Choose library dependacy search

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem was solved after restarting Android Studio > rebuild project.

Answer (score 256):

Add

```
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
```

to [**repositories**](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:repositories(groovy.lang.Closure)) under [**allprojects**](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:allprojects(groovy.lang.Closure))  not under [**buildscript**](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:buildscript(groovy.lang.Closure)) see screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its also written there at [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) But I did not even notice it. Thanks again for bringing it to light!!

Comment: Why? Anywhere documented? Thank you:)

Comment: @Alston actually @ https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart . The problem is that it's not clear whether it's under allProjects or BuildScript

Comment: I had to add mine in settings.gradle repositories

Comment: I also had to add in settings.gradle under `dependencyResolutionManagement {
    ...
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}` which only worked

Answer (score 19):

Above solutions did not work for me. I used below to get MPAndroidChart lib working on my project.

1. Downloaded the latest MPAndroidChart jar from:  https://jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.0.1/MPAndroidChart-v3.0.1.jar
2. Copied the downloaded MPAndroidChart-v3.0.1.jar file to YourProject/app/lib directory
3. Compiled the following dependency at app level build.gradle

   ```
   dependencies {

       compile files('libs/MPAndroidChart-v3.0.1.jar')

   }
   ```
4. re-sync the gradle

Comment: Thank you, this was the only way my app works

Answer (score 14):

Go to `build.gradle` Add the `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }` in both `buildscript{}` 
and `allprojects{}` as below :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}



allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Remember to `Sync`.

Answer (score 13):

Putting

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

in build.gradle in app folder fixed my issue!

Answer (score 9):

I solved this by putting `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }` inside repositories in `settings.gradle`

Answer (score 8):

In Settings Gradle just add this following code:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Man
I got this error in android studio latest version(Arctic Fox)

Answer (score 8):

for new android studio version set repository in `settings.gradle` file

```
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
     // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
}
```

Comment: This did it for me!! 
I just had to move  --> maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } to setting.graddle... Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem after adding this one in the gradle solved my problem:

```
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }

`
```

Answer (score 5):

For me the issue was resolved by placing code in below order.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could encounter this issue if your gradle offline mode is enabled.

turn it off in android studio, **Settings > Gradle and uncheck "Offline work"** and sync.

Answer (score 2):

I had to move `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }` to be the last declaration after `google()`, and `jcenter()`.

Comment: No need for changing the order. IN my case this worked.                            
 allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        jcenter()
        google()
     
    }
}

Answer (score 2):

As the Android studio is updated so you have to control your dependency form your `setting.app`

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Kindly place this line the respiratory

```
maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' } //as i have done above
```

Answer (score 1):

Or just rebuild your project. Worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Build-> Rebuild the project, then re-sync the gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

One Problem can also be, that you are behind a proxy.
So there are two possibilities: 
Add your proxy config to android Studio, ore you can also add a gradle.properties file in your project root.
there you have to enter the following credentials:

```
    systemProp.http.proxyPassword=
    systemProp.http.proxyHost=
    systemProp.http.proxyUser=
    systemProp.http.proxyPort=
    systemProp.https.proxyPassword=
    systemProp.https.proxyHost=
    systemProp.https.proxyUser=
    systemProp.https.proxyPort=
```

So the https Properties are pretty necessary. I figured out that often the repositories are available over both protocols. but sometimes only over http or https.

Answer (score 0):

Run gradle wrapper task from command line

```
cd ~/AndroidStudioProject/myproject/myapp
./gradlew tasks
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.
If your under proxy add this lines in gradle properties(project properties)

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost= "Your proxy"
systemProp.http.proxyPort= "Proxy port"
systemProp.https.proxyHost= "Your proxy"
systemProp.https.proxyPort= "Proxy port"
```

Answer (score 0):

The JitPack repository shouldn't be under buildscripts in this case. It should be just under repositories:

Answer (score 0):

[image: Don't forgot jetpack.io]

As you can see [here on medium](https://medium.com/@yilmazvolkan/kotlinlinecharts-c2a730226ff1) or [here on the github](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart#gradle-setup) you have to copy the lib of MPChart AND the Jetpack. There is no reason to fail if you do this.

Don't forgot jetpack.io

Comment: I think you meant jitpack.io, not jetpack.io.