# Unable to resolve the dependency

Tags: android, material-design, mpandroidchart

My app.gradle looks like this-:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.transenigma.iskconapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.12.0'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:1.5.0'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.9.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'it.neokree:MaterialTabs:0.11'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.0'
}
```

But when I sync then there is error-:

Error:(50, 13) Failed to resolve: it.neokree:MaterialTabs:0.11
Error:(51, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.0

I have included maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } but still there is error.

I moved it inside the repositries still the same result-:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.transenigma.iskconapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.12.0'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:1.5.0'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.9.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'it.neokree:MaterialTabs:0.11'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.0'
}
```

Comment: Just move  `maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }` under `repositories`. You should have only one `repositories`

Comment: @M D I have included inside one repositories but the error persisits.

Comment: I think its the same problem I solved: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37892027/2267723

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
```

to

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
```

Comment: I tried this also but the result was same. same error was thrown

Comment: are u using studio in offline mode

Comment: File->Settings->build exe etc->build tools->gradle->offline work if it is selected unselect it

Comment: it was unselected previously

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103065/discussion-between-ankitagrawal-and-pranav-shukla).