# Failed to resolve: com.github.PhilJay.MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, mpandroidchart, jitpack

When building, Gradle gave me the `Failed to resolve: com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4` error.

I already added `jitpack` in `build.gradle` here:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'aar'
        }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is based [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37892027/1968739). What am I missing?

Comment: what does the gradle console say exactly?

Comment: @AndroidMechanic It says `Failed to resolve: com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4` and points to the module `build.gradle` on this line: `compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch to the latest version:

```
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.0-beta1'
```

And always use information for the main source - in this case [MPAndroidChart Github Repo Readme.MD](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)

If behind a proxy configure your proxy settings in `gradle.properties` as follows:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=103.7.11.34
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyHost=103.7.11.34
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
```

**Note:** IP address and port in the lines above to be replaced by your proxy server ip address (or url) and port

Comment: same thing. Now it says `Failed to resolve: com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.0-beta1`. Is there a jitpack problem regarding this?

Comment: are you behind a proxy server ? if yes, pur the proxy settings in gradle.properties file and try

Comment: Is that just a random proxy IP address?

Comment: its common sense that one must you his/her own proxy server and port, but let me make that explicit by putting an instruction in the answer for those who may need spoon-feeding

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you added below plugin in your build.gradle where you add dependancy of
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4'
"apply plugin: 'maven'"

Answer (score -1):

> `Did you add the following in your root build.gradle file: if not then add this.`

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

And Restart `Android Studio` and `Rebuild` your project.

> I have faced same problem the problem was solved after restarting `android studio` --> `rebuild project.`
>
> Also if not solved with above you may change the `version` of `distributionUrl` in `gradle-wrapper.properties` to the available [newest](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/).

Comment: You can directly point to existing posts instead of copying and pasting answers and causing duplication - Source of text above - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32718820/failed-to-resolve-com-github-philjaympandroidchartv2-1-4?noredirect=1&lq=1