# Android Error:(35,13) Failed to resolve:com.Github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart.2.1.6

Tags: android, git, github, version-control, mpandroidchart

I am trying to run an application in android studio after importing from git and also running the same code from my local machine which was there before importing.
Both the times, i'm getting the same error.
**(35,13) Failed to resolve:com.Github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart.2.1.6**

I tried most of the solutions that have already mentioned in stack overflow, Not working still.
Please help me!! and i'm sharing the corresponding screen shot of the error.

Comment: It's usually good to post more of your error log (I don't see the promised screenshot, though it's usually easier to just copy and paste it into your question); it looks as if your app can't find a dependency that wasn't imported (does that need to be added in your build.gradle file?). A link to the Github project in question may also help.

Comment: Thanks for the response dear hBrent. By the way, I couldn't share the link for my Github project, it's quite confidential. Thank you

Comment: You can refer related issue in https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/1426 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32718820/failed-to-resolve-com-github-philjaympandroidchartv2-1-4/37892027#37892027.