# Failing To Generate APK - Getting ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.github.2359media:Easy AndroidAnimations:0.8

Tags: android-studio, mobile, apk

I've been trying to generate an apk from a finished app build in Android Studio 3.4.1. However, it is showing the error

> ERROR: Failed to resolve: `com.github.2359media:Easy AndroidAnimations:0.8` and I am not sure where or what to address that can solve this issue.

I've seen a question similar ([Failed to resolve: com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32718820/failed-to-resolve-com-github-philjaympandroidchartv2-1-4)) but all of this was already set.

I have the SDK set up (went through that issue already of having it in a default user folder with a space in the name), and the JDK, NDK as well. I am also running Android Studio as admin (even installed it as admin).

I also have

```
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

set in repositories

Surely I have a configuration wrong, but I am not sure what this error is telling me and where I need to look.

This is the build.gradle for the project:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and for the module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.alpha.calllog.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
   }
}
repositories {
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-beta1'
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.10.13'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.1'
implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
implementation 'com.github.angads25:toggle:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.zcweng:switch-button:0.0.3@aar'
implementation 'net.igenius:customcheckbox:1.3'
implementation 'com.github.2359media:EasyAndroidAnimations:0.8'


}
```

The messages in the lower right window of Android Studio say:

> Could not find com.github.2359media:EasyAndroidAnimations:0.8.
>
> Searched in the following locations:
>       file:/C:/devious/tools/extras/m2repository/com/github/2359media/EasyAndroidAnimations/0.8/EasyAndroidAnimations-0.8.pom

And many more files in the same directory, but when I look there in Explorer, there is no such directory of course. How should these directories be created? Do I need to? It seems as if these are created through some process but I don't know which process(s).

To me this is indicating that I didn't configure something correctly or something needs to be updated in the code somewhere.

Comment: Create a [mre].

Comment: There's no example to produce. I'm going through the process of generating an apk and the error above is what I get.

Comment: "before I set off to research them, it couldn't hurt to ask here for guidance on what I need to be looking at" Typically we expect the opposite -- do research first before asking. At the very least, can you please edit your question to link to the similar question you found?

Comment: This is part of the research. I simply don't know where to look. 

Rather than a lesson on how I should ask a question, perhaps any of you likely know what I'm dealing with and could just as easily say: "look at this file and edit xyz-parameter, as they are responsible for abc-function/scenario/situation."

I'm not asking for the fix, but for what I need to look at to even know where to focus on for the fix.

Thanks for that level of understanding.

Comment: Something else missing from your question is your build.gradle file. Please follow the instructions in Zoe's link to add a minimal reproduction to your question. Please also add the link to the question you found and tried already, as I asked before. We don't want to repeat things you've already tried, but we can't know what you've already tried unless you tell us.

Comment: edited the question with the two build.gradle codes @TylerH

Answer (score 0):

Actually fixed this by downloading a jar from GitGub and adding to the libs folder, and then editing the module build.gradle with this 
'files('libs/easyandroidanimationslibrary-v0.5.jar')' 
under dependencies.