# MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0 not working in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, charts, build.gradle, mpandroidchart

I am trying to do this -

```
dependencies {
    implementation("com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0")
}
```

Sync is successful but when I am running the app it is throwing these errors -

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0.
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0.
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
```

There are many errors but these are the top ones.
What should I do?

Comment: Have you added?  ```repositories {
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}``` to your root gradle or gradle.settings?

Comment: See this :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70322414/mpandroidchart-v3-1-0-could-not-find-on-github

Comment: it is working now